# How do I get an if statement with window.location.pathname in JS/Jquery to not include anything after the pathname?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get this URL "http://www.example.com/**womens-collection/ceramic**" to redirect to a URL, "http://www.example.com/the-ceramic".  Below is the code

```
   if(window.location.pathname == "/womens-collection/ceramic") {
   //alert("worked");
   document.location = "/the-ceramic";
   //$('#jbw-spot-mobile_details').toggleClass('opened')}
```

Works fine but I do not want any of the other URLs that are products to be affected by this like "http://www.example.com/womens-collection**/ceramic?page=shop.product_details**"

How can I get jquery to only recognize "/womens-collection/ceramic" and not anything after that?

Comment: Do you use some backend code? E.g. PHP or ASP or whatever?

Comment: Check whether there is any query string or do a substring and find the occurence of "?" in the url

Comment: Should be handled server-side, otherwise you're serving one page just to reject it and replace it with another page, which you also have to serve. The only reasons you may wish to do this sort of thing client-side are (a) inadequate server-side environment (b) lack of access to server-side environment (c) redirection is dependent on user interaction(s) with the originally served page.

Answer (score 2):

```
regex = /(/womens-collection/ceramic)$/i; // Using the i flag for case insensitivity. Feel free to remove if you want.
path = window.location.pathname;
if (path.match(regex)) {
   // Do stuff.
}
```

Just using regex to match at the *end* of the path.

Comment: What if there's a slash, question mark (without params), or hash on the end?

Comment: Then change the regex to /(/womens-collection/ceramic[#?/]*)$/ or /(/womens-collection/ceramic[#?/]?)$/ or however else one feels.

Answer (score 1):

[window.location.search](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp) returns the QS portion.

```
if(window.location.pathname == "/womens-collection/ceramic")
{
    if(!window.location.search)
    {
        // do your thing
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not combined the if statements?

Comment: @AdamMerrifield. You can, the code is just to demonstrate. OP/readers can use their preference.

Comment: 'if(window.location.pathname == "/advanced_search/?with=") {
   alert("worked");
   }'
how can you make the pathname with "?with=" work?